# Calling a chain of functions at different class inheritance levels

Tags: c++, method-chaining

Given:

```
class Foo {
 public:
   void Method1();
}
class Bar extends Foo {
 public:
   Bar* Method2();
}
class Baz extends Bar {
 public:
   Baz* Method3();
}
```

So,

```
someObject *b = new Baz();
b->Method3()->Method2()->Method1();
```

This will work, as `Baz()` contains all methods including `Method2()`, `Bar` contains `Method1()`;

But, due to return type this seems to be a bad idea - when accessing simpler `Method1()` at first inheritance level before calling more complex `Method3()`, *and* having to keep this calls in single line..

```
b->Method1()->Method2()->Method(3); // will not work?
```

Also, someone told me that putting `try.. catch.. throw` inside one of those `Method's` will occasionally exit the chain without calling next method at wrong value. Is this true?

So how to properly implement method chaining in C++?

Comment: This isn't valid C++ syntax, by the way.

Comment: **Lookup [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and weep.** It provides the same functionality without `virtual` methods but it's WAY MORE complicated to implement.

Comment: @CodeAngry somehow it was on habrahabr.ru same day you mentioned it here..

Comment: @kagali-san Every year or so I google around to see if a new easier-than-CRTP, non-virtual functions technique appears. And every year, I go back to CRTP. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what virtual methods are for. From the syntax errors I gather that you are new to C++

```
struct Base
{
    virtual Base* One() { return this; };
    void TemplateMethod() { this->One(); }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    virtual Base* One() { /* do something */ return Base::One(); }
};
```

When you call TemplateMethod:

```
int main() 
{ 

      Base* d = new Derived();
      d->TemplateMethod(); // *will* call Derived::One() because it's virtual

      delete d;

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `Derived::One` can return a `Derived*` rather than a `Base*` due to C++'s support for covariant return types, which may be what the OP is looking for...

Comment: I doubt it: the OP was worried, instead, about chaining these (so the actual polymorphism was the worry). Also, you couldn't return `Base::One()` in that case (without... erm... casting - ugly)